# Is the sentence, "When I opened the letter, it was written in Spanish..." grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

I am writing a tech blog. In this blog, I am using an analogy to explain something. And the analogy has this story that begins in Spain. And there's a sentence I used to convey a part of that analogy but now I am not sure if that sentence is grammatically correct or not.

So what I actually want to convey to the readers of this blog is that `I received a letter, I opened it but the language in which the letter was written was Spanish.` And to convey that I wrote, `When I opened the letter, it was written in Spanish...`. I don't know why but it seems like it is incomplete. Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When I opened the letter, it was written in Spanish…”** Is it grammatically correct??

hmm, another one of those awkward sounding sentences. I suspect if I was to say it is not correct I will find someone who differs and the same if I say it is correct.

When I opened the letter, **I found** it was written in Spanish… Is how I would write this

[CED; Found](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/find); past simple and past participle of find----find; verb (DISCOVER)

When I opened the letter, **I discovered** it was written in Spanish

A1 [ T ]
to discover

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you could be saying the letter was written in another language right up to the time it was opened, when it magically changed to Spanish.